# Python Regular Expression String Substitution Question

Tags: python

I have the text `"level": NumberInt(3)` and I want to replace it with `"level": 3`. How do I do it using replace? I've tried this so far so it's not working

```
o.level = str(s.replace(r'[^0-9]', ''))
print(o.level)
```

But I keep getting `"level": NumberInt(3)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
s = '"level": NumberInt(3)'
re.sub(r'NumberInt\((\d+)\)', r'\1', s)
```

```
'"level": 3'
```